# Industry Standard code PHP and JSON data via ajax or direct output

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I always have problem with these two php code. Both works perfectly and have no problem but i want to ask you guys what is industry standard. Is it ok to flush out html with php this way.

```
    foreach($items as $item){

echo '<div class="well">
          <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span3">
               <img src="' . $item[0] . '"> 
                 <ul id="info">
                  <li>Author : '.$item[1].'</li>
                  <li>Release Date: '.$item[2].'</li>
                </ul>
               </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <h3>' . $item[3] . ' by ' . $item[1] . '</h3>
            <p>' . $item[4] . '</p>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  ';

}
```

Another way is to echo out only json values

```
foreach($items as $item){

jsonencode($item);

}
```

After this i wil have to parse into browser using templating engine and parse them using Tempojs or Mustache.

So second way is cleaner code but parsing in DOM is mess without templating engine and first one will work much better in all browser and mobile devices .

So please provide me a suggestion  ,what should i use and which code follows industry standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as “industry standard” code. PHP and JavaScript are a general languages and developers can do whatever with them. Over the years though, common patterns and approaches have emerged. This is where things like design patterns come about.

In response to your problem, you want to pass data only, you don’t want to be passing anything template/display-related at all. When you do, you create larger HTTP requests and you’re also making assumptions about the final output.

Have a method that returns the data as an array or object, then if using PHP pass it to a HTML template with PHP tags in; or if request via JavaScript a Mustache template as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of echoing out a long concatenated string, the standard php templating tags are prefered: eg:

```
<?php //do stuff ?> or <?= //stuff to be echoed ?>
```

Doing this turns your first code block into:

```
<?php foreach($items as $item): ?>

    <div class="well">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span3">
           <img src="<?=$item[0]?>"> 
           <ul id="info">
             <li>Author : <?=$item[1]?></li>
             <li>Release Date: <?=$item[2]?></li>
           </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="span9">
           <h3><?=$item[3]?> by <?=$item[1]?></h3>
           <p><?=$item[4]?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```